# Criar usuario no AD com C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

Alguém tem um código para criação de user no ad em C# .net?
Sou novato em desenvolvimento em C# e tentei através dos códigos que vi aqui e não consegui

Comment: A pergunta é boa (+1). Apenas uma sugestão, você poderia incluir o código que já tentou e não funcionou. Assim pessoas que estão passando pelo mesmo problema com código parecido podem se beneficiar mais ainda com a questão.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer isso com a classe `UserPrincipal`. Ela representa um usuário do seu domínio. Quando você constroi ela você pode passar uma instância de `PrincipalContext`. Essa última classe encapsula o servidor ou domínio em relação ao qual as operações (como por exemplo de criação de usuário) são executadas.

Essa classe tem um construtor que você passa o chamado `ContextType` que pode ter os seguintes valores:

- `ContextType.ApplicationDirectory`
- `ContextType.Domain`
- `ContextType.Machine`

Esse `ContextType` representa o armazenamento do qual o principal faz parte. No caso de criar um usuário no AD você passaria `ContextType.Domain`.

Daí você só tem que criar uma instância de `UserPrincipal` passando o `PrincipalContext` que você criou, definir as propriedades e salvar. Fica assim:

```
using (var contextoPrincipal = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (var usuarioPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(contextoPrincipal))
    {
        usuarioPrincipal.SamAccountName = <Nome de Usuario Aqui>;
        usuarioPrincipal.EmailAddress = <Email Aqui>;
        usuarioPrincipal.SetPassword(<Senha Aqui>);
        usuarioPrincipal.Enabled = true; // Aqui você ativa essa conta, poderia não ativar, dependendo do caso de uso
        usuarioPrincipal.ExpirePasswordNow();
        usuarioPrincipal.Save();
    }
}
```

### Referências:

- Pergunta no SO [Creating Active Directory user with password in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305857/creating-active-directory-user-with-password-in-c-sharp)
- Classe `UserPrincipal` no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Classe `PrincipalContext` no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- Enumeração `ContextType` no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.contexttype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: tem como obter o departament e title da aba organization com UserPrincipal?

Comment: @Jhonatan, é possível sim, tem um jeito de acessar algumas propriedades, acho que funciona pra essas. Não quer postar isso como uma nova pergunta? Aí eu respondo um jeito lá e já fica mais fácil de achar pra quem precisar disso depois.

Comment: Obrigado! pergunta postada em: [link] http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23252/obter-organization-departament-e-organization-title-com-userprincipal-ad-e-c