# Obter Organization/Departament e Organization/Title com UserPrincipal - AD e C#

Tags: c#, autenticação, active-directory

Estou usando a referência System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement e eu tenho o código abaixo:

```
string dnsAD = "USINA.REDE";
string groupName = "Grupo Controle Acesso Gestao de Ativos"; //seta o grupo de acesso
PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dnsAD);
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName);
if (principalContext.ValidateCredentials(Login, Senha))
{
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, Login);
    if (!(userPrincipal == null) && (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(groupPrincipal))) //verifica se user é membro do grupo
```

Gostaria se dentro deste contexto, usando UserPrincipal, consigo obter informações da Organization, como Departament e Title?

Desde já agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe `UserPrincipal` em conjunto com uma classe chamada `DirectoryEntry` para acessar algumas propriedades do principal. Essa classe representa um nó ou objeto da hierarquia do Active Directory. A classe `UserPrincipal` herda de uma classe `Principal` que por sua vez está associada a um `DirectoryEntry`.

Para obter o `DirectoryEntry` sobrejacente de um `Principal` usamos o método `GetUnderlyingObject` dessa classe. Acontece que todo objeto `DirectoryEntry` tem uma coleção chamada `Properties` que tem as propriedades ADDS para aquele objeto do active directory. Essa propriedade é do tipo `PropertyCollection` e possui um método `Contains` pra verificar se uma propriedade é especificada para aquela entrada do AD.

Basicamente isso se faz assim:

```
directoryEntry.Properties.Contains("propriedade");
```

Isso é um `bool` que diz se a propriedade está lá ou não. Se a propriedade está você pode acessar o valor dela com sintaxe de array e acessando a propriedade `Value`:

```
directoryEntry.Properties["propriedade"].Value.ToString();
```

Com essa ideia, o melhor que você pode fazer é criar métodos de extensão pra deixar tudo mais flexível. Crie um método de extensão para a classe `Principal` que retorna uma propriedade do `DirectoryEntry` sobrejacente assim:

```
public static string GetProperty(this Principal principal, string propriedade)
{
    DirectoryEntry directoryEntrySobrejacente = principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

    if (directoryEntrySobrejacente.Properties.Contains(propriedade))
    {
        return directoryEntrySobrejacente.Properties[propriedade].Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Depois crie métodos de extensão pra as propriedades específicas que você quer. Por exemplo, um método `GetDepartment` pra retornar a propriedade department passando o nome da propriedade como string.

Não sei muito sobre AD então não sei se essa abordagem funciona exatamente para o seu problema. Tente aí e diga se deu certo.

### Referências

- [Pergunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785751/how-to-get-company-and-department-from-active-directory-given-a-userprincipa) no SO
- Classe `DirectoryEntry` no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.properties.aspx)
- Classe `Principal` no [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: obrigado! eu fiz assim 
 UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, Login);
            DirectoryEntry userDE = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
            var nome = userPrincipal.Name;
            var email = userPrincipal.EmailAddress;            
            var dpto = userDE.Properties["Department"].Value.ToString();
            var posicao = userDE.Properties["Title"].Value.ToString();

Comment: É pode ser também, o uso de métodos de extensão era só pra reutilizar código. Pra essas propriedades funcionou como esperado ?